# How to extract information from a command prompt using shell script?

Tags: shell, command-line-interface

I need a shell script using which I can fetch data from command prompt. I need to fetch data from the command prompt of a router. When I write commands in a shell script it goes the prompt but not executing the next command. So running the script just stuck in the prompt. Bellow is my script file

```
#!/bin/sh
ccli    
rsc
```

where ccli is the command to enter the prompt and rsc is the command to fetch some infomation.

So please suggest some method.

Answer (score 0):

If `ccli` reads commands from stdin (which I don't know), you might get further with

```
printf 'rsc\n' | ccli
```

For more complicated tasks I suggest you look into `expect` which was invented for the sole reason of driving interactive programs in a scripted way.

Comment: using printf 'rsc\n' | ccli
CVMX_SHARED: 0x1201c0000-0x1201f0000
Active coremask = 0x7
Console dev: pipe:[218860]
No entry for terminal type "xterm";
using dumb terminal settings.
Segmentation fault

Comment: @kernelCoder Well, if ccli segfaults, it's a bug you should report to the vendor.